# Simple broadband RF generator

Tags: rf, signal, generator

How to make a generator of RF signal which have multiple signal outputs ?
Details:

```
Fout = [ F0, .., Fn-1, Fn ] , where
    F0-F1 = F1-F0 = .. = Fn - Fn-1 = const 1000 Hz (i.e. constant stepping)
    F0 is ajustable from 0.1MHz to 10MHz
    n is somewhere about 100 steps
```

I can't use white noise sources over a single wave because signal must have uniform spectre and provide constant output to each step frequency.

Comment: Which part of generating an RF signal are you having trouble with?  There are entire instruments that can do this, you will need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: This is for my amateur project in medicine, environmental RF simulator of 10 watt power for testing on mices. I'm looking where to start to make it work, because i dont even know terminology. I just have specs of output, and it should be like describe above, to make experiments credible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note that the first half of this answer steers down the path of using two square waves BUT this won't generate all the harmonics - see edited section at bottom.**

A single square wave has odd harmonics of the fundamental frequency but these harmonics reduce with frequency. To counter this, feed the square wave through a filter to shape the harmonics to be of equal amplitude. Here is a picture of the basic harmonics inside a square wave: -

[image]

As can be seen from the picture, a single square wave gets you half of what you appear to require. Next, do the same with a square wave at twice the fundamental frequency. This then fills in the even harmonic gaps. **(No it doesn't - see edit below)**

It should be noted that the energy spectrum of a square wave falls off at 6dB per octave so a simple high pass filter (differentiator) will restore the energy to remain pretty flat over a wide desired band of frequencies. Note also that in doing this you are creating a repetitive impulse and, if anyone remembers college days then you'll know that this type of waveform has a flat frequency spectrum.

Finally feed those two waveforms into a summing amplifier and use a final low pass filter stage to kill off spectra above the high point at 100x the fundamental.

**EDIT**

Damn those crazy harmonics and my befuddled mind. The best way is to use a waveform that has all the harmonics present and I believe the easiest type is the sawtooth: -

[image]

Forget about two sq waves - just use a sawtooth waveform and add emphasis, via a filter to restore the 6dB/osctave roll-off to a flat response.

Comment: "This then fills in the even harmonic gaps." ... the first generator gives F,3F,5F,7F etc ... the second gives 2F, 6F, 10F, 14F ... leaving gaps at 4F, 8F, 12F etc. Interesting problem, slightly reminiscent of the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ha ha you are dead right so, swallow a spider to catch the fly... maybe the 2nd sq wave should be at half F with its fundamental suppressed? I'm thinking about this one....

Comment: The filter you need is an ideal differentiator -- which, if you think about it, turns your sawtooth into a series of impulses. See my answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed I mentioned that a couple sentences before the edit section "Note also that in doing this you are creating a repetitive impulse and, if anyone remembers college days then you'll know that this type of waveform has a flat frequency spectrum."

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [marker generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=marker%20generator).

You generate an extremely narrow, extremely fast rise and fall pulse at the desired spacing.  The harmonics of the pulse will appear at all multiples of the spacing frequency.

If, for example, you generate very narrow fast pulses at 100 kHz, you will generate harmonic signals at 100 kHz, 200 kHz, 300 kHz, ...

The rise and fall times determine how high the harmonic series goes before decaying to nothing.  Faster edges give more higher harmonics.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the inverse Fourier Transform of a series of impulses in the frequency domain is ... a series of impulses in the time domain. (and vice-versa)

This is one reason that an unshielded ignition system on a gas engine can blanket the entire AM broadcast band with noise.

If you amplitude-modulate the time-domain impulses, you'll see the sidebands appear around each of the "carriers" in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 1):

At higher frequencies, what you are describing is often called a [comb generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_generator), because the spectrum looks like the teeth of a hair comb when viewed on a spectrum analyzer.

As other answers have said, it works by generating a train of accurately timed pulses in the time domain.